# Why aren't all the badges shown on the track menu?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I like using the 'Track Badges' menu on my profile a lot (I know what you're going to say, I just have a knack for these things), but I keep noticing something a bit unusual.

Many of the Badges featured on the actual list do not get featured on this menu. For example, I've been hoping to be able to track progress for the *Pundit* badge (ten comments with score of five or more), but **it doesn't show up in the menu**.

**Why not?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Many of the Badges featured on the actual list do not get featured on this menu

It is a problem of performance.

Some of the badges are very computation/database intensive to award, let alone to track in (near) real-time *per* user.

Such badges are not trackable for this reason.

Comment: Can you please give a list of the untrackable badges, just that we know?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I might be able to do that. Should that be a separate, self-answered question, then?

Comment: @Texenox good question, but in my opinion it is better be posted here, to complete Oded's answer. :)

Answer (score 18):

As Oded has stated, some badges are too resource-intensive already to award. Tracking them would only cause much more unnecessary load.

Others may not be tracked because they are obsolete (e.g. Precognitive/Beta, Analytical).

### These are the currently untrackable badges.

(*m* indicates a badge that can be awarded multiple times.)

#### Question Badges

*(Silver) **[Favourite Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question)***: Question favorited by 25 users. *m*
*(Gold) **[Stellar Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/stellar-question)***: Question favorited by 100 users. *m*

*(Bronze) **[Nice Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question)***: Question score of 10 or more. *m*
*(Silver) **[Good Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question)***: Question score of 25 or more. *m*
*(Gold) **[Great Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/22/great-question)***: Question score of 100 or more. *m*

*(Bronze) **[Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question)***: Question with 1000 or more views. *m*
*(Silver) **[Notable Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question)***: Question with 2500 or more views. *m*
*(Gold) **[Famous Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question)***: Question with 10000 or more views. *m*

#### Answer Badges

*(Silver) **[Enlightened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)***: First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more. *m*

*(Silver) **[Generalist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist)***: Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.

*(Silver) **[Guru](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru)***: Accepted answer and score of 40 or more. *m*

*(Silver) **[Lifejacket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/313/lifejacket)***: Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more. *m*
*(Gold) **[Lifeboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/314/lifeboat)***: Answer score of 20 or more to a question score of -3 or less that goes on to receive a score of 3 or more. *m*

*(Bronze) **[Nice Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer)***: Answer score of 10 or more. *m*
*(Silver) **[Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer)***: Answer score of 25 or more. *m*
*(Gold) **[Great Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer)***: Answer score of 100 or more. *m*

*(Gold) **[Populist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/populist)***: Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. *m*

*(Silver) **[Tenacious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/69/tenacious)***: Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.
*(Gold) **[Unsung Hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/unsung-hero)***: Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

#### Participation Badges

*(Silver) **[Pundit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/pundit)***: Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

*(Bronze) **[Precognitive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/131/precognitive)***: Followed the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase.

*(Bronze) **[Talkative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/130/talkative)***: Post 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com).
*(Silver) **[Outspoken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/138/outspoken)***: Post 10 messages in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com) starred by 10 different users.

*(Silver) **[Yearling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling)***: Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. *m*

#### Moderation Badges

*(Gold) **[Constable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/constable)***: Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation.
*(Gold) **[Sheriff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/208/sheriff)***: Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year.

*(Silver) **[Reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/169/reviewer)***: Complete at least 250 [review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) tasks. *This badge is awarded once per review queue*
*(Gold) **[Steward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward)***: Complete at least 1,000 [review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) tasks. *This badge is awarded once per review queue*

*[Note: Reviewer and Steward can be tracked from the review queue itself.]*

*(Bronze) **[Synonymizer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/150/synonymizer)***: First approved [tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

*(Silver) **[Taxonomist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist)***: Create a tag used by 50 questions.

#### Other Badges

*(Bronze) **[Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer)***: Share a link to a question later visited by 25 unique IP addresses. *m*
*(Silver) **[Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster)***: Share a link to a question later visited by 300 unique IP addresses. *m*
*(Gold) **[Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist)***: Share a link to a question later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses. *m*

#### Tag Badges

One can track Tag Badges by switching the 'Next Privilege' menu to a 'Track next Tag Badge' menu.

Comment: It seems that also [lifeboat and lifejacket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/lifejacket-lifeboat-badges/info) cannot be tracked.

Comment: Can you still earn these badges?